# Download file from server into Ionic2 App

Tags: android, ios, cordova, angular, ionic2

I am in need to implement a feature in my `Ionic2` app where users can download a specific Video file into Ionic2 app.

Upon checking the `Ionic Native` section, I found that the following plugins available :

- File
- File Chooser
- File Opener
- File Path

But could not find anything such as '[cordova-plugin-file-transfer](http://cordova.apache.org/docs/en/6.x/reference/cordova-plugin-file-transfer/index.html#download)' where a specific method exists as **DOWNLOAD**.

What could be the way out ?

Please suggest.

Comment: By download, what exactly do you mean bro..? Is the file stored on a server and you want to save it on your phone's filesystem..? All the plugins you have mentioned above are used to open files on your phone's internal memory / card storage..

Comment: @RajaYogan - Yes. I need to have a functionality like WhatsApp. User will have a button to download - when tapped - the video file would be downloaded into the phone's storage and saved for future use.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use [**Transfer**](https://ionicframework.com/docs/native/transfer/) native plugin for that.

> This plugin allows you to upload and download files.

[**Git Repo.**](https://github.com/apache/cordova-plugin-file-transfer)

```
 ionic plugin add cordova-plugin-file-transfer
 npm install --save @ionic-native/transfer
```

Comment: Thank you very much. I see a download method there and I think that would work. Thanks again.

Answer (score 5):

You should use "**Transfer**" plugin for downloading a file in ionic2

You can install plugin by this command

```
ionic plugin add cordova-plugin-file-transfer
npm install --save @ionic-native/transfer
```

and then import it

```
import { Transfer, FileUploadOptions, TransferObject } from '@ionic-native/transfer';
```

set constructor

```
constructor(private transfer: Transfer, private file: File) { }
```

Then use this function to download file using url

```
download() {
const url = 'http://www.example.com/file.pdf';
fileTransfer.download(url, this.file.dataDirectory + 
'file.pdf').then((entry) => {
console.log('download complete: ' + entry.toURL());
}, (error) => {
// handle error
});
}
```

Hope it help you
You can also upload a file using this Plugin

Comment: What if there is no absolute path ? and how to handle these kind of url  like url = "server/controller/test?emp=10" ; let destPath = this.file.externalDataDirectory + 'file.pdf'; this.fileTransfer.download(url, destPath, true).then((entry) => { this.test = 'download complete: ' + entry.toURL() }, (error) => { this.test = 'download err: ' + error.json() });

Answer (score 1):

First of all. `transfer` plugin that everyone is referring to here is deprecated. You should never use deprecated plugin if there's alternative.

Gladly, Ionic provides you alternative
[Native Http plugin](https://ionicframework.com/docs/native/http/)

HTTP service has `uploadFile` and `downloadFile` methods that you can use to hanlde uploading/downloading of files.

`downloadFile` method has 4 parameters: `url`, `body`, `headers`, `filepath`.

In most simple case calling of this method will be like this:

```
this.nativeHttp.downloadFile(urlWithFile, {}, {}, fileNameToSave)
```

It returns promise that resolves with `FileEntry` instance which you can use to read the from file system in future (if you need)

`fileNameToSave` you can get from `File` class. Basically, it can be `this.file.tempDirectory + fileName` or you can pick another directories from `file` like `this.file.dataDirectory + fileName`

Again, you should NEVER use deprecated plugins/packages. They are called deprecated for a reason

P.S. if you want then to open downloaded file you can do it with [@ionic-native/file-opener](https://ionicframework.com/docs/native/file-opener/) plugin like this:

```
this.file.resolveLocalFilesystemUrl(fileEntry.toURL())
         .then((entry: FileEntry) => {  
             entry.file(meta => {
                 this.fileOpener.open(fileEntry.toURL(), meta.type)
             }, error => {});
         })
```

Answer (score 0):

you can simply download plugin using

```
 ionic cordova plugin add cordova-plugin-file-transfer
```

Answer (score 0):

It should be like below

1. Add imports

   import { Transfer, TransferObject } from '@ionic-native/transfer';
2. Constructor

   constructor(private  transfer: Transfer) {
       }
3. Create a instance of fileTransfer

   const fileTransfer: TransferObject = this.transfer.create();
4. final code

   fileTransfer.download("your URL", "you URLmime tyoe").then((entry) => {

   }, (error) => {
           // handle error
         });

that's all.

Thanks