# how to download file from url in Ionic 2 or Ionic 3?

Tags: ionic2

I am trying this code but not working:

```
    this.fileTransfer.download(this.urls, this.file.dataDirectory +'001.pdf',true).then((entry) => {
  console.log('download complete: ' + entry.toURL());
}, (error) => {

});
```

Any help on above.

Comment: You can try Cordova file transfer plugin for this . https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43233691/download-file-from-server-into-ionic2-app

Comment: maybe not the best way anymore as described on the readme of the plugin the plugin is now deprecated and you should move to xhr2 https://cordova.apache.org/blog/2017/10/18/from-filetransfer-to-xhr2.html